# Plot symbolic derivative of a built-in MATLAB function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compute the second derivative of the airy function. Only its first derivative is a predefined function in MATLAB (`airy(1,x)`)

Is there a way to compute its symbolic derivative? without resorting to finite differences, etc

I tried this

```
syms x
aiprime = @(x) airy(1,x);
aisecond = diff(airy(1,x));

plot(-10:0.01:10,aiprime,aisecond)
```

But didn't work.

```
Error using plot
Invalid second data argument
```

Comment: Based on the [Airy functions' defining differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) I'd suspect that `y'' = y*x`, i.e. `diff(airy(x),2) == x*airy(x)`. Special functions are real handy. And are you aware of how `plot` works in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your plot statement. You specify the desired `x`-data, but did not evaluate your function in these points:

```
syms x
aiprime(x) = airy(1,x); % I would define it as a symbolic function instead of a function handle, although it works too.
aisecond(x) = diff(airy(1,x)); % Define as a function, to be able to evaluate the function easily

xs = -10:0.01:10; % define your desired x points
plot(xs,aiprime(xs),xs, aisecond(xs)) % evaluate your functions and plot data
```

[image]